# OS partitions suddenly unmounted themselves

Tags: hard-disk, disk-usage, disk, ssd, fdisk

**Previos similar problem**

Since I installed PopOS! 20.04 there was a problem, after 10 minutes using the OS it just close all my working windows, stop the Gnome interactions (I mean it doesn't change buttons style when I pass the mouse over it) and then it log me out and doesn't allow me to log or change of Virtual Environment (ctr+alt+F2, or F3, or F4). Then it show a error in an infinite loop forcing me to shut down the machine by brute force.

It stop happened some weeks ago, and today it returns, but now i could see some error messages after the infinite loop of error messages starts. By what I said is an error where the / partition and the /home partition just unmounted themselves and then remount with only read rights.

[Here is the picture of the error messages mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FagY2.jpg)

**The error**

As you can see in the picture, the sda3 and sda5 were remounted but with read permissions only while I was working and this stop all my system forcing me to shut down by brute force.

The sda3 and sda5 partitions are my / and /home partitions respectively, here the `fdisk -l sda`

```
Dispositivo   Comienzo      Final   Sectores Tamaño Tipo
/dev/sda1           34      32767      32734    16M Reservado para Microsoft
/dev/sda2        32768 1539839999 1539807232 734.2G Datos básicos de Microsoft
/dev/sda3   1539840000 1663571966  123731967    59G Sistema de ficheros de Linux
/dev/sda4   1663571968 1665669118    2097151  1024M Sistema EFI
/dev/sda5   1665669120 1875384318  209715199   100G Sistema de ficheros de Linux
```

It's in Spanish but the Linux, Microsoft and EFI partitions are easy to identify.

**SDA disk details**

So this disk have 5 partitions:

SDA1  Is a partition that Windows made because I first use the disk in that OS.

SDA2  Is my NTFS partition. I use it to save my games, some school works, and basically all my data. I use it in Linux and Windows.

SDA3  Is the root partition for PopOs!

SDA4  Is the /boot partition for PopOs!

SDA5  Is the /home partition for PopOs!

**The question (if necessary)**

How to avoid that my root and /home partition unmount themmself while I'm using my Linux?
Or how to solve the problem?

**Tools used**

*fsck* As root. I didn't make it scan all disk beacause if i did, the output was nothing.

```
fsck from util-linux 2.34
[/usr/sbin/fsck.ext2 (1) -- /dev/sda] fsck.ext2 -c /dev/sda 
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sda
```

*HDSentinel* Again, as root.

```
    HDD Device  0: /dev/sda
HDD Model ID : ADATA SU650
HDD Serial No: 2J1920116172
HDD Revision : V8X11c55
HDD Size     : 915715 MB
Interface    : S-ATA Gen3, 6 Gbps
Temperature  : 50 °C
Highest Temp.: 50 °C
Health       : 100 %
Performance  : 100 %
Power on time: 37 days, 9 hours
Est. lifetime: more than 1000 days
  The status of the solid state disk is PERFECT. Problematic or weak sectors were not found. 
    No actions needed.
```